# Help for resynthesize install

Tags: software-installation, plugins, gimp

I do not understand how to download and install the plug-in `resynthesize` in Gimp 10.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the standard version (apt repository), or a "flatpak"/"snap"/"AppImage" version?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question relates to specific software rather than Ubuntu, so you might find you will get better assistance if you post to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Regardless I have found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1230344/installing-gimp-plugin-in-ubuntuxenial) post which states you only need to run:

```
sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
```

This will install many useful Gimp plugins automatically, including resynthesize.

Here's a simple guide:

Press CTRL + ALT + T to open a terminal.
It will look something like this
[image: Blank terminal.]

Enter the command `sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry` (it is case sensitive so make sure that's right).

[image: terminal with command.]

Press enter and it will ask for your password, enter that and press enter. While you are typing the password the terminal will not change.

[image: Terminal requesting password.]

The plugins will then install, once it's finished you can close the terminal.

[image: Terminal finished installing.]

If you re-open Gimp you can see the plug-in installed in the plug-in browser.

[image: Gimp plug-ins]

Comment: Scusme but for install Resinthesize in Gimp I must have Ubuntu?

Comment: @GiuseppeLogo No, the plugin works [on other operating systems](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer), however this is the AskUbuntu stack exchange, so I assumed you were using Ubuntu. If you're using another operating system then you should ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for better advice :)